# Bootstrap optgroup selection

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using [bootstrap select plugin](https://github.com/silviomoreto/bootstrap-select) with bootstrap 3.0.2, which fulfils most of my requirements.
The only additional functionality I want is to be able to select an `optgroup` by clicking it.

For example I would like to select Picnic (picture below) just like any other option,
[image]
[Bootsrap select page](http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/3/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has little to do with Bootstrap. `optgroup`s in HTML are not designed to selected. My suggestion would be to drop them all together and just make them normal `option`s with a class and style them differently. However keep in mind, that many browsers are limited to how you can style `options`, so make sure you test this in multiple browsers.

Comment: This is not practical. Thinking about have to select 500 items from 2000, for example.

Comment: @Khrys I'm not quite sure what that has to do with the original question, but I'd suggest using checkboxes.

Comment: It has everything to do with the topic. The Bootstrap Select has a workaround for this: https://github.com/silviomoreto/bootstrap-select/issues/1159#issuecomment-153998138 The owner are studing to implement this.